C++ std::weak_ptr::lock() seems to be executed at the same time as the destructor
I have a scenario where I need to use weak_ptr to cache resource, and use shared_ptr externally to determine the life cycle of the resource. When applying for this resource, I must ensure that it was released last time.But I found a problem.I write a demo, for example:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A {
    A() {
        cout << "A apply resource" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "A release begin" << endl;
        // do some release work
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes (60));
        cout << "A release end" << endl;
    }
};

std::weak_ptr<A> wptr;

shared_ptr<A> GetOrCreateA()
{
    auto ptr = wptr.lock();
    if (ptr) {
        cout << "not null" << endl;
        // do something
    } else {
        // will create new A resoruce, but may the resource was not released last time(in destructor) yet
        auto newA = std::make_shared<A>();
        // cahce
        wptr = newA;
    }
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1([]() {
        // fine
        auto ptr = GetOrCreateA();
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds (2));

    // not fine
    auto ptr = GetOrCreateA();

    t1.join();
    cout << "main quit";
}


the result is:
A apply resource
A release begin
A apply resource
A release begin

I found that weak_ptr lock() returns null, which does not mean that the destruction has been completed.So the second resource application may fail(assume this kind of resource can only be applied for after it has been released last time.)。
Is there any good way to handle this scenario? thanks

Once destructor is called you are done, you should not be able reach the object. It doesn't matter that destructor is still running.  So this std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes (60)); in a destructor is big WAT!

Here is your code tweaked to run on godbold: https://godbolt.org/z/5KobKxfTY

Just to clarify wptr.lock() will start return null as soon as there is no strong reference, so just before destructor is called. It must be impossible to get strong reference after destructor is called (basically you can't cancel execution of destructor).

@MareR thanks comment, I don't want to get the last strong reference. The key to the problem is that I want to ensure that after the last resource is released（releasing the resource may take a little time）, then I can apply for new resources.

@MareR The ideal result is:1.A apply resource2.A release begin3.A release end4.A apply resource

"I found that weak_ptr lock() returns non-null" -- I don't understand, the output you provide clearly says that the pointer is null!

The two threads access wptr without mutual exclusion. (At least I think that sleep_for does not provide any sort of synchronization guarantees.) If you move t1.join() before wptr.lock(), you get the "synchronizes with" relationship implied by join() and you are fine.

@xf do it with thread synchronization then. wait on a condition variable and notify it when resource is released for example

@UlrichEckhardt Sorry, my mistake， I have corrected it
